# Data layer(Models) is asp.net MVC MEF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, data-access-layer

I made my ASP.NET MVC 5 project modular(pluggable) with MEF
In my website users come and can install new plugins, delete them or update them
I don't know what to do with my data access layer(I mean where should my models place)?
if I create a new project for my models every time a user install/delete/update a plugin that project show update and it's not good because dll is running,
what can I do?
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of have one class for one entity you can have for example 3 classes for all:

Type (Id, Name)
Property (TypeId, DataTypeId, Value)
PropertyValue (PropertyId, Value)

It's very flexibly approach but less fast because of number of tables and queries.

Added:

So when your customer want to add plugin you just crate new Type, add it's properties and their values.

Comment: the users add plugins run time, really I didn't get what you mean

Comment: ok, what is plugin in our case? if it is 'real' C# type that is derived from some your base type (or implements some interface) and it's located in assembly, you can load this assembly into memory and use that type with EF 'code first' approach.

Comment: my plugins are class library projects that become al part of the main website,

Comment: I still can't understand what is the problem. can you describe it more clear? Where users of your website get plugins? They make them? Do the have access to source code or they upload plugins via http?..

Comment: I'm creating something like a CMS, It's an online shop, Then the project is finished I want to upload it and Users can come and register and use it with different plugins(for example a plugin that shows product sales in a chart), it's like (www.prestashop.com), now I want to know what to do with my models, because the models and contexts will be repeated if each module has its own models and context, so if I can't explain it clear, Thanks for answering

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should make one project-assembly YourCmsName.Models.Core and one separate project-assembly like YourCmsName.Models.SomeFeatureName for each plugin. You also can create sql-script for every plugin and base core sql to setup db. So your user will download Core project-solution and then plugin projects and will add reference to them from main solution. So, every additional project-assembly should contains only specific models because it will be able to use shared core types.

Comment: I undertood what you say, but the problem is if additional project-assemblis have specific models for their own, maybe PluginB needs one or more of PluginA's models(I mean there is a table in database that need to use it in multiple plugins), so I have to write models for each plugin even they are one model, isn't it a problem?

Comment: If plugin A and plugin B use same model you should separate this model in project C and name it like something 'shared'. And it will be dependency. So, 'if you want plugin A you should also setup this shared project to'.

Comment: again thanks for your answer, I don't know how many plugins this system have, I made it modular so I can make a plugin and user can add it without changing the core and main website, if there is already plugin A and a few months later I want to make a new plugin named Plugin B that has plugin A's models and something more, in this case Plugin A have not to be changed